# RoR: How to use *_path in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to generate a “report” in a model. This “report” has to include links. However, all the *_path functions seems to be unavailable in the model classes (a simple test show me that new_post_path raises an Exception in my models, but works fine in my controllers)

Is there any way to use polymorphic_url or, at least, *_path methods in my models ?

Comment: Are you trying to generate links back to the model?  Like if your model was a mapped resource in your routes.rb?

Comment: Generally speaking this breaks MVC. Since the model shouldn't know anything about the View. The Report is really just another view of the data stored in the model(s). You should probably be generating the report in a controller, as opposed to trying to add the routes to the model (which causes it to be tightly coupled)

Comment: I’m perfectly aware that it breaks MVC ; however, the proper way to achieve what I want to do would be to define a DSL like textile. KISS: I prefer a minor breakage of MVC. The report is not a view ; it’s a method used in several views ; it’s more like a view helper, but which need to access implementation-specific parts of the model — putting it in the view would be a MVC breakage too, far more worse IMO.

Comment: From the question and the word report it sounds like you where generating something.  What about using a shared partial to include it in several views?

Answer (score 0):

if you:

```
include ActionController::PolymorphicRoutes
```

In your model:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionController::PolymorphicRoutes
end
```

you get `polymorphic_path` and `polymorphic_url`.  These can then be used by passing `self` into the methods if you're generating a route for the current AR object.

Comment: Doesn't work ; Rails.logger.debug polymorphic_url(Post.last) give me undefined method `post_url'

Comment: hmm... must require some other modules in there to create post_url.  Try looking at the docs for ActionController::PolymorphicRoutes: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes.html

Comment: Seems like *_url and *_path are protected instance methods of ActionController::Base. Looks like I’ll have to find another way.